# Convert textbox value to int

Tags: c#, wpf, database, exception, formatexception

I have a database and I assigned the price of a product from that database into a textbox. Whenever I try to convert the textbox value into an int, I receive a Format exception. I use the following code to convert:

```
unitsA = Int32.Parse(units.Text);
```

And the database value is a smallint.

Comment: What is in `units.Text` when the call fails?

Comment: @PatrickHofman units is the name of my textbox.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What for text is in the textbox?

Comment: @PatrickHofman is not asking what is `units`, but what is the content of it

Comment: Check [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: Number of available units, which is a smallint

Comment: Give us an example, because if it is a int number it shouldn't throw a format exception

Comment: <TextBox x:Name="units" Text="{Binding UnitsInStock}" />

Im using this code to insert the value and the code in my question to format, but for some reason I receive a format exception and I do not know why.

Comment: Why don't you just use the value from the UnitsInStock property?

Comment: @mm8 The only way I know is to convert to an int, because I want to take the value in a int form to use it later

Comment: What's the point of binding to UnitsInStock then? You should take the value from this source property.

Comment: @mm8 I am doing that, I just named the textbox where the binding is, units

Answer (score 3):

If the value of units.Text can not be converted as `int` you'll get an exception.

You could use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` to handle exceptions.

```
int number;
if(!int.TryParse(units.Text, out number))
{
    //error handling
}
```

Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to get more information about `TryParse`.

Comment: I did that, but I still get an exception when I try to format it inside the if condition.

Comment: In my example the if condition matches when you can't parse it. Maybe you have not recognized the ! in my answer. When you can parse it your result will be stored in number. That's why I added the link to the TryParse method from the MSDN. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

**Never trust user input.**
Use `Int.TryParse` instead of `Int.Parse`.
This way you don't have to deal with exceptions if the input can't be parsed as an int value.

Replace `unitsA = Int32.Parse(units.Text);` with:

```
int unitsA;
if(Int32.TryParse(units.Text, out unitsA)
{
    // Do your stuff.
}
else
{
    // Alert the user.
}
```